# Error al importar componente en Vue: This dependency was not found:

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Intento importar un componente (Footer.vue) tan simplemente como lo he hecho con el componente TodoList.vue :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import TodoList from '@/components/TodoList'
import Footer from "@/component/Footer"

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'TodoList',
      component: TodoList
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Footer",
      component: Footer
    }
  ]
})
```

Sin embargo me aparece el siguiente error (antes ya de añadirlo también en las routes de Router, pero no cambia nada al añadir la ruta):

```js
This dependency was not found:

* @/component/Footer in ./src/router/index.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/component/Footer
```

En el Footer.vue lo tengo de la misma manera que el otro que si se importa correctamente:

```js
<script>
export default {
    name: "Footer"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Has escrito `"@/component/Footer"` y debería ser `"@/components/Footer"`

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo Gracias, vaya error simple que no vi. Era eso efectivamente.